# What controls are there in the built in player?

Tags: interface

While using the <kbd>F11</kbd> *Play Rendered Animation* window, I have noticed that when you click or press any keys it will pause automatic playback. This lead me to the question,  what controls are there? Is it possible to start automatic playback again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- <kbd>A</kbd> - toggle frame skipping.
- <kbd>P</kbd> toggle ping-pong.
- **<kbd>↵ Enter</kbd> start playback (when paused).**
- <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> toggle looping.
- <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> manual frame stepping.
- <kbd>←</kbd> step back one frame.
- <kbd>→</kbd> step forward one frame.
- <kbd>↓</kbd> step back 10 frames.
- <kbd>↑</kbd> step forward 10 frames.
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> use backward playback.
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> use forward playback.
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> hold to show frame numbers.
- <kbd>LMB</kbd> scrub in time.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> zoom in
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> zoom out
- <kbd>F</kbd> flip image on the Y axis
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> flip image on the X axis
- <kbd>I</kbd> show frame indicator
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> quit

## Playback speed

- <kbd>1 NumPad</kbd> 60 fps
- <kbd>2 NumPad</kbd> 50 fps
- <kbd>3 NumPad</kbd> 30 fps
- <kbd>4 NumPad</kbd> 25 fps
- <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4 NumPad</kbd> 24 fps
- <kbd>5 NumPad</kbd> 20 fps
- <kbd>6 NumPad</kbd> 15 fps
- <kbd>7 NumPad</kbd> 12 fps
- <kbd>8 NumPad</kbd> 10 fps
- <kbd>9 NumPad</kbd> 6 fps
- <kbd>/ NumPad</kbd> 5 fps
- <kbd>-</kbd> slow down playback.
- <kbd>+</kbd> speed up playback.

[**See also the Blender manual.**](http://blender.org/manual/render/display.html)